# Material-UI ListItem Component for Right Toggle

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This seems so basic that I feel I must be misunderstanding how it works. I have a simple demo component that renders a material-ui List with three ListItems. Each list item has a toggle on the right hand side implemented using the rightToggle prop. For the purposes of demonstration each toggle is generated differently.

The first is a basic material-ui Toggle component. The second is a custom component wrapping a Toggle and the third is generated by a function call.

Some code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import { List, ListItem } from 'material-ui/List';
import Toggle from 'material-ui/Toggle';
import MyToggleComponent from './MyToggleComponent';


const myToggleFunction = id => <Toggle onClick={() => console.log(id)} />;

const TestPage = () =>
    <div>
        <Paper style={{ width: 500, padding: 15, margin: 25 }}>
            <List>
                <ListItem
                    primaryText="This is the first list item"
                    secondaryText="This toggle for this item is directly defined"
                    rightToggle={<Toggle onClick={() => console.log('1 - clicked')} />}
                />
                <ListItem
                    primaryText="This is the second list item"
                    secondaryText="This toggle is generated from a component"
                    rightToggle={<MyToggleComponent text="2 - clicked" />}
                />
                <ListItem
                    primaryText="This is the third list item"
                    secondaryText="This toggle is generated programatically"
                    rightToggle={myToggleFunction('3 - clicked')}
                />
            </List>
        </Paper>
    </div>;

export default TestPage;
```

and the custom component - very basic

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Toggle from 'material-ui/Toggle';


const MyToggleComponent = ({ text }) => <Toggle onClick={() => console.log(text)} />;

MyToggleComponent.propTypes = {
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default MyToggleComponent;
```

Results in:

[image: Material-UI List with misplaced Toggle]

All three toggles generate the expected console output. The first and third items render as I would expect with a Toggle to the right of the list item. But the second, using a custom component, renders the Toggle above  the list item. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @ArslanTariq - Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Material-UI is [cloning](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) these elements under the hood and is adding/injecting a prop **style**. In the first and third example the actual values are the Material UI defined components that accept a property **style** as documented [here](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/toggle). Your own defined component however only passes the text property and does nothing with style.

So comes down to that all 3 examples get passed a style prop but only the first and third do something with it. To bad this wasn't well documented.

[image]

It kinda does say it needs to be a Toggle element and your own component isn't one because it wraps the Toggle component.

```js
pushElement(children, element, baseStyles, additionalProps) {
    if (element) {
      const styles = Object.assign({}, baseStyles, element.props.style);
      children.push(
        React.cloneElement(element, { // element is your own defined component
          key: children.length,
          style: styles, // here the style property is passed
          ...additionalProps, // your text property is passed here
        })
      );
    }   
}
```

[source](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/77fbba7b12dbeb902f7c0529907fb5d52e6857d3/src/List/ListItem.js#L551)

So to fix this change:

```js
const MyToggleComponent = ({ text }) => <Toggle onClick={() => console.log(text)} />;
```

to:

```js
const MyToggleComponent = ({ text, style }) => 
<Toggle style={style} onClick={() => console.log(text)} />;
```

Comment: You're right is is not immediately obvious to someone not versed in all the intricacies of React but that does the trick. I now have my toggle in the right place.